# error tags in prime function caller

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions, primes

I am geting error codes:  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol and error tag fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals and i dont know why.

I have never encounterd this before and have no idea how to fix it.

I have looked at many other codes containing the same errors and still need help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int isPrime (int n);
int main() {
    int num;
    for(num = 1; num <= 542; num++) {
        isPrime(num);
    }
// pause and exit
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int isprime(int var1) {
    int i, count;
    count = 0;
    for(i = 2; i <= var1/2; i++){
        if(var1 % i == 0){
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(count == 0 && var1 != 1){
        cout << var1 << endl;
        return var1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fist answer is the best! I feel so stupid

Answer (score 0):

C++ is case sensitive, and you declare `isPrime` and define `isprime`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)'s what you need to know about this error.